# How can we see on Cirq that Google Sycamore has 54 qubits?

Tags: quantum-gate, cirq, google-sycamore

[image]

Hello, can you explain how to see in Google Cirq that the figure above is a 54 qubits quantum computer ? thanks

Comment: Just count the tuples (i,j)

Answer (score 0):

Just count the (a,b). They are 54. Or look at google's official docs, what the circuit diagram signifies.

https://quantumai.google/cirq/build/circuits

Answer (score 0):

Using Cirq, you can do the following:

```python
import cirq_google

my_device = cirq_google.Sycamore
metadata = my_device.metadata
# Then:
print(len(metadata.qubit_set))
# Or,
print(len(metadata.nx_graph.nodes))
```